# Convert List[List[Any]] into List[List[String]] in Scala

Tags: string, scala, list

I have the following `List[List[Any]]` which I want to convert to `List[List[String]]`.

```
val input:List[List[Any]] = List(List(1234), List(234, 678), List(8765, 90876, 1))
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
val output:List[List[String]] = List(List(1234), List(234, 678), List(8765, 90876, 1))
```

I have tried doing the following:

```
val output:List[List[String]] = input.map(_.toString).toList
// or 
val output:List[List[String]] = input.map(_.toString)
```

None of the above give me the desired output.

Comment: `input.map(_.map(_.toString))`

Comment: Yup. This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, your list is nested, you need to map it twice.

Why below is not working?

```
val output:List[List[String]] = input.map(_.toString)
```

Because, `_ placeholder` holds value of type `List[String]` and applying `toString` method convert the `List` to `String` and hence result will be of type `List[String]` instead of `List[List[String]]`.

```
scala> input.map(_.toString)
res2: List[String] = List(List(1234), List(234, 678), List(8765, 90876, 1))
```

Therefore, you need to map input twice.

```
scala> input.map(_.map(_.toString))
res0: List[List[String]] = List(List(1234), List(234, 678), List(8765, 90876, 1))
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.